# Как использовать редактор bootstrap-wysiwyg?

Tags: wysiwyg, bootstrap

Есть редактор для сайта [`bootstrap-wysiwyg`](http://mindmup.github.io/bootstrap-wysiwyg/).

Написано, что он превращает в редактор любой див.
Вопрос в следующем: куда сохраняется результат редактирования?
Другие редакторы используют текстареа, и там всё ясно. Имя текстового поля - 
это переменная, которую сохраняем. А что передавать из дива?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Use standard jQuery methods to access and set content..

Что означает "используйте стандартные методы jQuery для получения и изменения содержимого.."
А значит:

```
var content = $('#editor').html();
```

Comment: А что значит var content = $('#editor').html();?

Comment: Получить html-код из элемента с ``ID=editor``  
Почитайте о ``jQuery``, ``CSS селекторах``

Comment: Хорошо, понял. Спасибо.

Comment: А что здесь в базу заносить? В какую переменную текст сохраняется?

Answer (score 2):

Или без js

```
documnet.getElementById('id вашего дива').wysiwyg();
```

Comment: Видимо,без jQuery,но какой смысл обходиться без него, если разговор про плагин для того же jQuery?